# can Mobile Application add WCFServices reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am begin mvc4 asp.net using visual studio 2012, so maybe this is simple question.

On the client, I use mobile application, 
I can add services reference WCFServices but I can not call Services class to call function.

what is your recommend for me ?

thankyou very much

Comment: are you receiving some sort of error when you try to call the functions you've added the reference to?

Comment: no,after I add Service reference, I can not call ServicesClient class,Can asp.net mobile application work with WCFServices or it must work Web API ?

Comment: so your client is not Asp.Net MVC then?

Comment: no,I used mobile application with using mvc4, would you like to explain for me the difference the WCFServices and Web-API? and step by step to create Web-API and mobile application on 2 difference projects ?

Comment: again question,WCFServices can work with mvc4 Mobile application or just only Web API can work with Mobile Application ?

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense, Asp.Net Mvc4 is a Web Framework, all the WCF Service calls would be made on the server, the Mobile piece are only Mobile Templates to make the HTML output look nice on Mobile devices. Also, WebAPI is built on top of Mvc4 for your controllers to output JSON instead of HTML.  So if you are using Asp.net Mvc4 then you are already using WebAPI.  If you aren't making WCF Service calls from the server, then you aren't using the Mvc4 framework....

Comment: Dear Andrew, I thankyou very much your explain,I read many topic but your answers is very specific for me.

Comment: Dear Mr Andrew,is Web API response for Mobile Application a json ? if so, what would your recommand to show the json of list items to the table or a gridview on Mobile application ? what way is easy

Comment: Dear Andrew, If you can, I would like add your skype ? my skype id: sacpv04